# Superconducting gap function vs condensation energy

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity, condensation, mean-field-theory

Within BCS mean-field theory, what is the relationship between the superconducting gap function (or the superconducting order parameter $\Delta(k)$) and the condensation energy (the energy gained by an electron to form a Cooper pair)? Are they referring to the same quantity?

If they two quantities are indeed synonyms, how can we explain why it is sometimes energetically favorable to form a nodal superconductor (e.g. Helium-3A phase), where there are zeros in $\Delta(k)$?

Comment: I think part of the confusion here may stem from your definition of the condensation energy. The condensation energy is generally understand to be the energy difference between the BCS state and the normal state, not the energy gain in forming a single cooper pair. See for example [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/433802/133394)